# Duda caracteres de Python EDIATDO

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy ejecutando un programa con acentos y caracteres extraños como *alçada*, algo que no he había influido en nada pero que ahora al guardarlo, se ha convertido en: *alÃ§ada* (es la primera vez que me pasa, nunca he tenido ningún problema).

O *número* a *nÃºmero*.

Me gustaría comprender porque a veces, al guardar el programa se cambia. Estoy usando la última versión de Python y nunca había tenido un problema de estos. Soy consciente que es preferible hacer un programa sin acentos... para evitar problemas pero me gustaría saber el porqué.

Cabe la posibilidad de hacer un programa con estos símbolos raros y que no te los cambiase? El problema lo he tenido con la última versión de Spyder (hay alguna opción de guardado o algo?).

Muchísimas gracias y perdonen por mi ignorancia.

**EDITADO**

Gracias a @abulafia me he dado cuenta (me lo ha dicho básicamente) que necesito cambiar la codificación de guardado de Spyder a utf-8. Si alguien sabe hacerlo que por favor me escriba.

Comment: No uso Spyder, pero estoy seguro de que el problema viene, como sospechas, de alguna opción de guardado. Los caracteres no-ascii pueden guardarse de diferentes formas, según la _codificación_ (_encoding_) elegida. El estándar hoy día es utf-8 y ese parece ser el que estás usando para guardar. Sin embargo, al volver a abrir el archivo en otro edtior que en vez de utf-8 use latin1 (o windows cp1252), las cosas se verán "mal", como tú describes. No queda muy claro en la pregunta en qué momento ves eso "mal", si al abrir el programa o al ejecutarlo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, El problema me lo he encontrado al guardar el programa y al abrirlo de nuevo. Determinando la codificación utf-8, no habría problemas con los caracteres ç, á, ú...? Gracias

Comment: Efectivamente, usando utf-8 tanto para guardar como para leer no tendrás problema con ningún carácter, pues en ese caso el juego de caracteres usado es Unicode, que incluye todas las letras acentuadas, eñes, .. y de hecho cualquier caracter de cualquier lenguaje humano (podrías si quisieras introducir texto en japonés, ruso, árabe...) Incluso los emojis forman parte de Unicode, por lo que también podrías usar emojis en las cadenas o comentarios del programa.

Comment: Aunque luego está el problema de la terminal desde la cual ejecutes el programa. Esa terminal también debe "entender" utf-8 o de lo contrario los `print()` que haga tu programa podrían verse raros. ¿En dónde ejecutarías tus programas?

Comment: Los ejecuto desde la misma consola de Spyder... supongo que poniendo al principio algo similar a `#coding: utf-8` No tendría que haber problema. También me aseguraré de ver cuál es la codificación del guardado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira a ver si la consola de spyder también tiene alguna opción que permita especificar con qué encoding funciona. Debe usar el mismo encoding que uses para guardar el archivo (utf8). El comentario que dices es para el propio intérprete de python y no es necesario a partir de python3, si el encoding es utf-8 ya que éste es el que Python3 usa por defecto. Pero el poner ese comentario no cambia enel encoding que esté usando el editor, que debe ser cambiado mediante alguna opción en el editor.